# How can I check if a individual in a column exists in multiple groups?

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have the data below:

```
group_id <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4)
member_id <- c(1,2,3,4,4,3,5,6,8,10,12,12)

df <- data.frame(group_id,member_id)

> df
   group_id member_id
1         1      1
2         1      2
3         1      3
4         2      4
5         2      4
6         2      3
7         3      5
8         3      6
9         3      8
10        3     10
11        4     12
12        4     12
```

Each member is paired with a group_id. I would like to extract which member id exists in multiple groups. For the above case, a `member_id` of 3 exists in both `group_id` 1 and 2. Is there a way I can use `data.table` or `dplyr` to figure out which `member_id`'s exist in more than one group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `n_distinct` in `dplyr` and `uniqueN` in `data.table` to get count of unique `group_id` in each `member_id`. Select only those `member_id` which occur more than once.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(member_id) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(group_id) > 1) %>%
  pull(member_id) %>% unique

#[1] 3
```

`data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
unique(setDT(df)[, .SD[uniqueN(group_id) > 1], member_id]$member_id)
```

and for completeion here is base R approach -

```
unique(subset(df, ave(group_id, member_id, FUN = function(x) 
       length(unique(x))) > 1, select = member_id))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
      group_by(member_id) %>%
      slice(which(n_distinct(group_id) > 1)) %>%
      ungroup %>%
      distinct(memberid) %>%
      pull(memberid)
```